# Sympy in for Loop runaway argument error

Tags: math-mode, python, exsheets

I am trying to have the following document compile using sympytex. The goal is to generate squares of integers using sympy and the latex forloop into exsheets. I have been trying to fix the error for hours to no avail. The indention seems to affect the type of errors. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\write18{}
\usepackage{forloop,python,sympytex}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[auto-label=true]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\begin{sympysilent}
  h=2*10
\end{sympysilent}
We know that $h=\sympy{h}$.
\newcounter{s}
\forloop[1]{s}{1}{\value{s}< 6}
{
\begin{sympysilent}
  h=4
  t=h*h
\end{sympysilent}

\begin{question}
  Hello is $\sympy{h}^2 =$
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  The answer is $\sympy{h}^2 = \sympy{t}$
\end{solution}
}

\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about *not* using `sympytex`?

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to `exsheets` and the fact that you use `\sympy` inside its environments. Using `{sympysilent}` inside `\forloop` alone already causes errors.